# Specifying doc-id and plot-id (i.e. the URL) for output_server()

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to be able to specify the URL where `output_server` publishes my app in `bokeh-server` (as an example, I am trying to do this in the [`animate_widgets.py`](https://github.com/chdoig/scipy2015-blaze-bokeh/blob/master/animate_widgets.py) example that Christine Doig presented in Scipy2015).

I am already running `bokeh-server` in a separate terminal. When I run my app with `output_server`, is there any way to specify the URL where the app will be rendered?

It seems to currently follow the syntax:

```
 http://localhost:5006/bokeh/doc/some-doc-id/some-plot-id
```

but I don't see the ability to specify those fields `<doc-id>` and `<plot-id>` with `output_server` (documentation for [`output_server`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/resources_embedding.html#bokeh.state.State.output_server) below).

Is there  any way to specify **where exactly** (URL-wise) I want the app to be published?

[image]

Note that just entering the string `http://localhost:5006/bokeh/doc/some-doc-id/some-plot-id` as URL for `output_server()` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is not really. Those URLs are meant to be unambiguous and to avoid collisions. Letting users choose their own URLs would be fairly unworkable in the general multi-user scenario. But that's OK, what you really probably want to is to embed a Bokeh server plot in your own document (as opposed to just linking to the bare page that has the plot and nothing else). This you can accomplish easily with `server_session`:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#bokeh-applications

Edit: I won't actually say its impossible, but it's far enough outside normal usage that I don't know offhand how you could accomplish it, and even if you could it would probably not be advisable for several reasons.

Comment: FYI here is an issue for updating the docs: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2563